# unpickling stack underflow in python while loading wordvectors

Tags: python

I want to load word vectors to jupyter notebook
I tried this small code

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec.load('G:\BABA\wiki.en.vec')
```

But i am getting error like this

> UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow

What should i do

Comment: I know nothing about `gensim`, but there are exactly two possibilities: 1) there is an error in `G:\BABA\wiki.en.vec`, or 2) there is an error in `gensim.models,Word2Vec.load`. I would suspect the former.